# In R, why is purrr's map2 ignoring my group_by argument when making plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, purrr

I have many plots that I need to create broken out by students' level. To do this, I want to use `map2` from the `purrr` package. I want one plot for each level (so 4 plots altogether), but when I do group_by, the code creates one plot for each student (16 unique plots). ***How do I get my code to make one plot for each grade rather than one for each student?**

```
#My data
library(dplyr)
my_data <- tibble(level = c(rep(c("Kindergarten", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"), 4)),
                  id = c(1:16),
                  score = c(81:96))
```

```
#My attempt at making one plot per level--makes 16 plots instead of 4

library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

#Extract information
levels <- my_data %>% pull(level) %>% as.character
scores <- my_data %>% pull(score)

#Make plots
my_plots <- map2(
  .x = levels,
  .y = scores,
  .f = ~{
    my_data %>%
      group_by(level) %>% # I don't know why this is being ignored
      ggplot(aes(x = .x, y = .y)) +
      geom_point() +
      ggtitle(str_glue("Score by {.x}"))
  }
)

my_plots #has 16 plots (one for each data point) instead of 4 (one for each level with each respective student represented)
```

Comment: There could be masking from another package, and/or you don’t have `dplyr` loaded -  try explicitly calling the command with `dplyr::group_by(…)`

Comment: @jpsmith , thanks for reaching out! I just tried that and got the same result unfortunately

Comment: `map2()` works with 16 pairs of values, so 16 is expected output length too. And I'm afraid    `dplyr::group_by()` does not have that effect on ggplot that you seem to assume.

Comment: @J.Sabree Perhaps you want to add either `group=` or `color=` in `ggplot` `aes` with `level`

Comment: @margusl but when I do just map(.x = levels, .f = ~ ....), I also get the same result. Wouldn't map just work off the levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code, i updated the code to use only map function with levels which we can use to filter the my_data

### code

```r
library(purrr)
levels <- my_data$level %>% unique()

#Make plots
my_plots <- map(
  .x = levels,
  .f = ~{
    my_data %>%
      filter(level == .x) %>% # I don't know why this is being ignored
      ggplot(aes(x = id, y = score)) +
      geom_point() +
      ggtitle(str_glue("Score by {.x}"))
  }
)

my_plots #has 16 plots (one for each data point) instead of 4 (one for each level with each respective student represented)
```

### output

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you! This is much closer than I was! One question, is there a way to just get a unique plot per level? Your code groups by everything, but it still makes 16 plots.

Comment: Actually, I found a scalable way to do it. Underneath where you define levels, you can also define levels_length <- length(my_data$level %>% unique())
and then where you have my_plots print, it can be my_plots[1:levels_length]
and will only print the unique ones. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I get 4 plots which i shared, not sure why you are getting 16 plots, if you run my code it will give 4 plots. you may check the titles as well

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a slightly different approach, which saves you a bit of coding (`map` instead of `map2`, less variables to be defined, and referencing becomes clearer).

First make a list by splitting your data frame, then create a plot for each.

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- tibble(level = c(rep(c("Kindergarten", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"), 4)),
                  id = c(1:16),
                  score = c(81:96))

my_data %>% 
  group_split(level) %>%
  ## or, which I prefer, with split (it makes a named list)
  # split(.$level) %>%
  map({
    ~ggplot(.x, aes(level, score)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle(str_glue("Score by {unique(.x$level)}"))
  }) %>%
  ## just for demo purpose
  patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on requirements I would rather use facets :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
my_data <- tibble(level = c(rep(c("Kindergarten", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"), 4)),
                  id = c(1:16),
                  score = c(81:96))

# fix level order
my_data$level <- fct_inorder(my_data$level)

# Single plot with facets by levels:
my_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = score)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(level))
```

[image]

For separate plots, splitting the dataframe itself seems more natural. `split()` creates list of data frames named by the factor value used for splitting (i.e `level` values in this case). Used `imap()` here to access list names through `.y`,

```r
# Separte plots by levels
library(patchwork)
plots <- imap(split(my_data, my_data$level),
              ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = id, y = score)) +
                geom_point() +
                ggtitle(.y)) 

# plots patched together to save some space
(plots[[1]] | plots[[2]]) / (plots[[3]] | plots[[4]])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: using patchwork::wrap_plots could save you a lot of typing

Comment: sure. Here I just wanted to make clear that we still deal with a list and each item can be individually accessed.